# ORA-00933 issue when using FETCH , OFFSET or PIVOTS

Tags: sql, oracle

Im currently using PL/SQL developer interface with Oracle 10g database structure and after being sure that those fields are exists in find_sales_person table , when i do execute the code structure below i do get 00933 issue in return.

```
Select * FROM
(
SELECT SALES_PERSON_CODE,CO_ID
FROM find_sales_person
)
PIVOT
(
COUNT (CO_ID)
FOR CO_ID IN ('91','2478')
)
ORDER BY CO_ID
```

As a second sample where i do get the same error is;

```
SELECT *
FROM abtp_param_l
ORDER BY ABT_PARAM_ID , CREATE_USER_ID
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
```

abtp_param_l is a view where contains at least 50 rows.I also tried the code with actual tables instead of views

Comment: `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY` works only in Oracle 12c. You are using features not present in 10g.

Comment: how about pivots ?

Comment: Its available form 11g only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Oracle features not available in Oracle 10g. `FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY` is available only in Oracle 12c and `PIVOT` is available from Oracle 11g onwards only.